# How to extract floor area from 3D data using the sf package

Tags: r, r-sf

I have the following 3D data from swisstopo, the Swiss Federal Office of Topography, on building volumes:

https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/landscape/build3D

To download the data, you need to click on read more, scroll down and click on sample data.

This is only a sample. Please note that I use GDB because my real data set comes in this format.
Then I read the data into R:

```
library(sf)

data <- st_read("swissbuildings3dlv03/GDB/swissBUILDINGS3d_10.gdb")
```

In a next step, I drop the third dimension and calculate the area:

```
data %>% 
 st_zm() %>% 
 st_area()
```

However, when comparing it to official data on these buildings, the area is always twice as large as it is supposed to be. I guess, something is wrong in how I reduce the dimension from 3D to 2D. Any help or hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to ask more R-spatial questions over on http://gis.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the first feature's geometry:

```
> st_as_text(st_geometry(map[1,]))
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z ( TIN Z .....
[...]
MULTIPOLYGON Z (((601608.1 197988.1 525.57, 601604 197974.8 525.57, 601593.7 197977.9 525.57, 601597.8 197991.3 525.57, 601608.1 197988.1 525.57)), ((601608.1 197988.1 517.9725, 601597.8 197991.3 517.9725, 601593.7 197977.9 517.9725, 601604 197974.8 517.9725, 601608.1 197988.1 517.9725))))"
```

The MULTIPOLYGON bit is relevant. It is composed of two POLYGONS:

```
> st_as_text(st_cast(st_collection_extract(st_geometry(map)[1]),"POLYGON"))
[1] "POLYGON Z ((601608.1 197988.1 525.57,
                 601604 197974.8 525.57,
                 601593.7 197977.9 525.57,
                 601597.8 197991.3 525.57,
                 601608.1 197988.1 525.57))"          
[2] "POLYGON Z ((601608.1 197988.1 517.9725,
                 601597.8 197991.3 517.9725,
                 601593.7 197977.9 517.9725,
                 601604 197974.8 517.9725,
                 601608.1 197988.1 517.9725))"
```

which looks like two identical polygons at different Z heights. Filtering through `st_zm` will result in two identical 2D polygons. Hence you'll get double the area.

If you are guaranteed that each feature is represented this way, then dividing by two to get the footprint area is valid. If there may be some other complexity (are there pyramids in Switzerland? Or maybe buildings shaped like Toblerone?) where the top polygon isn't the same as the bottom one then you'll need to extract the lowest polygon (if you want footprint on the ground) or the union of all polygons if you want area cover as seen from above.

Here's an example of `st_union` on the first feature halving the area by unioning the top and bottom polygons:

```
> st_area(st_union(st_collection_extract(st_geometry(map)[1])))
150.5087 [m^2]
```

compared to original:

```
> st_area(st_collection_extract(st_geometry(map)[1]))
301.0174 [m^2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I will contact them to confirm that the structure is always the same and hence extracting the first polygon is valid. One more question, what did you mean when editing my question with the (tidyverse) package should never be loaded the way I did?

Comment: Only load the specific packages that you use - for example `library(dplyr)` - rather than pulling in a entire cosmos of optional add-ons that you mostly aren't using and that other people might not want to have to install. Minimal examples are best examples.